# Django: ImportError: No module named ?z?

Tags: python, django, importerror, uwsgi

Hi I am trying to deploy a django app with uwsgi. I keep getting Import Errors that look like this:

ImportError: No module named ?z?

-or-

ImportError: No module named ?j?

-or-

ImportError: No module named `?6

So basically the output of the module seems like gibberish and I am unable to figure out the problem. Does anybody have an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: What file and line is the ImportError occurring on? What's the traceback?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have missed a comma in the settings.INSTALLED_APPS, after the app name. Go, check!